# Using Composition with WCF RIA Services

Tags: wcf, ria

I've been trying to find an example of how to used the CompositionAttribute with CUD operations when using LinqToEntitiesDomainService. I can't find one anywhere and really need this functionality in the next couple of days. Does anyone know how to implement this and can provide an example for me? The only resonable example I can find is at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/digital_ruminations/archive/2009/11/18/composition-support-in-ria-services.aspx

but it is based on L2S.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm late :)

Looking for something else your question showed up so I thought about giving you or somebody else a little light here.

I came across the same problem and talked a lot with some of the guys from the RIA team. It was so hard that I even [wrote a post about it](http://sgomez.blogspot.com/2011/03/wcf-ria-compositions.html).

Long story short, you need to update your parent entity first and then update any modified child entities.

I don't want to copy and paste all the code from my post go over there and take a look.